# Reshaping data input for the model from (1, 5) to (1, 3000)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, reshape

The training and testing data for the model has a shape of (rows, 3000). I like to call the model to predict A which has a shape of (1, 5). How do I reshape the variable A so the model will take it to return prediction? This is a text classification model, hence the data has been vectorized.

```
A = ['The dog is so cute']
A = vectorizer.fit_transform(A)

#pretrained model
classifier.predict(A)
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-90d6770bbdca> in <module>
----> 1 classifier.predict(a)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in predict(self, X)
    305             Predicted class label per sample.
    306         """
--> 307         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    308         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    309             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    285         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
    286             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
--> 287                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    288 
    289         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 5 features per sample; expecting 3000
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.fit_transform()` on `X`, you are refitting the vectorizer again on `X`. Use only `.transform()` and you should be okay:

```
A = ['The dog is so cute']
A = vectorizer.transform(A) # <-- change this line

#pretrained model
classifier.predict(A)
```

This is of course assuming `vectorizer` is **the same vectorizer you used to transform your training samples** and it has been fitted according to them.

Comment: Hi, I still got the same error with just vectorizer.transform(A). ValueError: X has 5 features per sample; expecting 3000

Comment: Apologized, I got it. I just had to retrain again. Thanks for your guidance!